# Erro "Assert: Shift is not as expected" ao criar relatório

Tags: java, relatório, pentaho

Criei um relatório no Pentaho Report Designer. São 13 gráficos de pizza seguidos, mudando apenas a consulta de um para outro. Quando acrescentei o gráfico número 11 e fui visualizar, obtive o erro abaixo.

Chequei o SQL da consulta e está válido e sem retornar nenhum valor estranho.

O erro é:

> org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.InvalidReportStateException: Assert: Shift is not as expected: realY=252100000 != expectation=251700000; Shift=63200000; AdditionalShift=-400000; RealShift=62800000

Eu gostaria de saber o que significa este erro, descrito acima, e como remediá-lo. Disponibilizei o [stacktrace completo](http://pastebin.com/Nd8LXbi8).

Comment: É um erro no componente JFreeReport, ligado a labels ou alturas (height, maxheight) dos elementos.

Post relacionado: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?161136-Uncoherent-values-in-maxheight-of-a-group-causes-Assert-Shift-is-not-as-expected#post372137